# Using IOS device to develop an Android game

Tags: unity-game-engine

as the title described my issue , my question seems to be dumb a little ; But because I don't own an Android device , But I published Android Apps using Genymotion Emulators. And I tried to download Unity Remote App on my Emulator but it does not work that well.

So my question here is : Can I use my iPhone device to test and develop the game that will be published to android users?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do that since the Input methods being touches do not differ. The only thing you have to keep in mind is the wide range of resolutions used by android devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use can use your iphone for testing but jusst for the logic. The performance and resolutions are very different for android. Also if there is any platform specefic code you have written in unity then you have to take care of that.
Besides using your iPhone you can generate an APK from unity and install it on the android emulators to test.